# loading a chessboard of squares javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I got a question. I'm trying to do a randomized chessboard-layout on my homepage (each time the site is loaded the divs will switch places). And this is what I've come up with:

```
<head>
<script>

    function shuffelSquares(squarenumber){
        for(var j, x, i = squarenumber.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = squarenumber[--i],         squarenumber[i] = squarenumber[j], squarenumber[j] = x);
            return squarenumber;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="background"></div>
<div class="chessBoard">

    <div class="menu">
        <li class="menu">PROJECTS</li>
        <li class="menu">CONTACT</li>
    </div>
    <script>

    var squareNumbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    squareNumbers = shuffelSquares(squareNumbers);
    for(var i = 0; i<=squareNumbers.length-1; i++){
        console.log(squareNumbers[i]);
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'square'+squareNumbers[i]);
        div.innerHTML = "<h1>" + squareNumbers[i] + "</h1>";
        console.log(div);
    }



    </script>
    <div id="square1"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div id="square2"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div id="square3"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div id="square4"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div id="square5"><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div id="square6"><h1>6</h1></div>
    <div id="square7"><h1>7</h1></div>
    <div id="square8"><h1>8</h1></div>
    <div id="square9"><h1>9</h1></div>
</div>
```

I want to replace the divs just. But document.write() is not the way to go as I understand.

Thanks for your replys. :)

Comment: I suggest you to first review HTML basics before jumping to JS. JS is (also) about elements manipulation, seeing your HTML markup you'll hardly go on with JS. `<li>` elements for example cannot go as `<div>` children. Also seeing the way you classify your elements using both `.menu` for your err DIV and LI implies that you're not using properly classNames and selectors.

Comment: Also remember that `h1` should be one-per-page if you want search engines to be kind in your confronts (SEO).

Comment: Well yes you are right but also not, this is just a prototype/mockup I just want my ideas working before cleaning up and validate my code. But thanks for the input you've got some points.

Comment: And yes I will use an UK instead of a div in my later design because it won't validate now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById(squareId).innerHTML = // ...`

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/erCCX/

```
<div id="square1">1</div>
<div id="square2">2</div>
<div id="square3">3</div>
<div id="square4">4</div>
<button id="btn">click me</button>    

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        document.getElementById("square" + i).innerHTML = "chess!";    
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `insertBefore` to achieve the result, I've created a small demo, just reload it a few times to see the layout changes: http://jsfiddle.net/gSV7K/1/

```
var article = document.querySelector('article');
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var x=0; x < elements.length; x++){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9.99) + 1;
    var randomElement = document.querySelector('div:nth-child(' + randomIndex + ')');
    article.insertBefore(randomElement, elements[x]);
}
```